# OpenCL on isolated CPU cores

Tags: opencl

I have an 8 core linux machine on which I've altered my grub.conf with

```
isolcpus=4,5,6,7
```

so that the last four cores are not used by the OS process scheduler. Running the command *clinfo* shows for the CPU: *MAX_COMPUTE_UNITS: 4*.
Removing the isolcpus line from my grub.conf file and running *clinfo* shows for the CPU: *MAX_COMPUTE_UNITS: 8*. I guess this means that any OpenCL kernel will not use the isolated CPUs. Does anyone know how to force an OpenCL kernel to use the isolated CPUs? More info on my specific OpenCL implementation from *clinfo*:

```
NAME:       Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2603 v2 @ 1.80GHz
VENDOR: Intel(R) Corporation
PROFILE: FULL_PROFILE
VERSION: OpenCL 1.2 (Build 8)
EXTENSIONS: cl_khr_icd cl_khr_global_int32_base_atomics cl_khr_global_int32_extended_atomics cl_khr_local_int32_base_atomics cl_khr_local_int32_extended_atomics cl_khr_byte_addressable_store cl_khr_spir cl_intel_exec_by_local_thread cl_khr_depth_images cl_khr_3d_image_writes cl_khr_fp64 
DRIVER_VERSION: 1.2.0.8
```

Comment: It's certainly going to depend on your OpenCL runtime; there is nothing in the specification about it. So check the vendor documentation for the runtime.

Comment: can you provide more info on your OpenCL implementation? If what you want to achieve is better partitioning of a NUMA system, take a look to the sub-device partitioning options of your vendor.

Comment: @Ruyk, I updated the post to include some additional info on my OpenCL implementation.